# PL-SQL PROCEDURE issue

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I'm trying this simple procedure using Oracle DB and SQL Developer:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_prod AS
   query_str VARCHAR2(200);
   i INTEGER := 0;

   TYPE cur IS REF CURSOR;
   my_cur cur;

BEGIN
   query_str := 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE ROWNUM<=1000';

   OPEN my_cur FOR query_str;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('start');

   LOOP
      i := i + 1;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('i: ' || i);
   END loop;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('COUNT: ' || i);

   CLOSE my_cur;
END;
```

The last value for 'i' is 3014 (the expected one is 1000) and the last 'put_line' is not displayed.

Moreover, if I try to put only the increment in the loop and then displaying the final value, the procedure doesn't end.

Anyone could suggest me where is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Your loop has no end condition.  I can't imagine how it stops at 3,014.  I speculate you want to do something with the cursor.  That would normally be why such a loop is set up.

Comment: btw you don't need `TYPE cur IS REF CURSOR;` since Oracle already provide `sys_refcursor`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to enter on specific cursor argument (you can find lot of tutorial on Internet / Oracle site).  Just to show you some little edit to YOUR stored procedure to make what you wanted (I don't this this proposed procedural is the best way to do that):

```
create or replace PROCEDURE TEST_PROD IS
   query_str VARCHAR2(200);
   i BINARY_INTEGER := 0;

   TYPE cur IS REF CURSOR;
   my_cur cur;

   TYPE rek IS TABLE OF table%ROWTYPE INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
   my_rek rek;
BEGIN
   query_str := 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE ROWNUM<=1000';

   OPEN my_cur FOR query_str;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('start');

   LOOP
      i := i + 1;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('i: ' || i);
      FETCH my_cur INTO my_rek(i) ;
      EXIT WHEN my_cur%NOTFOUND;
   END loop;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('COUNT: ' || i);
   CLOSE my_cur;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Aleksej has a good answer to use an implicit cursor where possible--implicit cursors close automatically and are succinct and readable.  For your example, implicit cursor is a recommended way to go.

I'll add here some additional examples somewhat in line with etsa's answer 
just for alternatives using explicit cursors as in your original post.

If you want to stop looping, you'll need an exit condition on your `LOOP`. 
  With an explicit You can exit when your counter reaches a specific value, or when your CURSOR has been exausted, or any other condition you like.

Example 1 with explicit cursor - exiting the loop when the cursor runs out of data:

Create a test table:

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE(MY_TABLE_DATA NUMBER);
```

And load it:

```
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE SELECT ROWNUM FROM ALL_OBJECTS WHERE ROWNUM < 100;
```

Then create your procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_PROD IS
  QUERY_STR VARCHAR2(200);
  I INTEGER := 0;
  TYPE CUR IS REF CURSOR;
  V_MY_TABLE_DATA MY_TABLE%ROWTYPE;
  MY_CUR CUR;
  BEGIN
    QUERY_STR := 'SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE ROWNUM<=5';
    OPEN MY_CUR FOR QUERY_STR;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('START');
    LOOP
      FETCH MY_CUR INTO V_MY_TABLE_DATA;
      EXIT WHEN MY_CUR%NOTFOUND;

      I := I + 1;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('I: ' || I);
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('MY-TABLE-DATA: ' || V_MY_TABLE_DATA.MY_TABLE_DATA);
    END LOOP;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('COUNT: ' || I);
    CLOSE MY_CUR;
  END;
/
```

And try it:

```
BEGIN
  TEST_PROD();
END;
  /
START
I: 1
MY-TABLE-DATA: 1
I: 2
MY-TABLE-DATA: 2
I: 3
MY-TABLE-DATA: 3
I: 4
MY-TABLE-DATA: 4
I: 5
MY-TABLE-DATA: 5
COUNT: 5
```

Or you can stop looping based on `I`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_PROD IS
  QUERY_STR VARCHAR2(200);
  I INTEGER := 0;
  TYPE CUR IS REF CURSOR;
  V_MY_TABLE_DATA MY_TABLE%ROWTYPE;
  MY_CUR CUR;
  BEGIN
    QUERY_STR := 'SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE ROWNUM<=10';
    OPEN MY_CUR FOR QUERY_STR;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('START');
    LOOP
      IF I >= 3 THEN
        EXIT;
      END IF;
      FETCH MY_CUR INTO V_MY_TABLE_DATA;
      I := I + 1;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('I: ' || I);
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('MY-TABLE-DATA: ' || V_MY_TABLE_DATA.MY_TABLE_DATA);
    END LOOP;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('COUNT: ' || I);
    CLOSE MY_CUR;
  END;
/

BEGIN
  TEST_PROD();
END;
  /

START
I: 1
MY-TABLE-DATA: 661
I: 2
MY-TABLE-DATA: 662
I: 3
MY-TABLE-DATA: 663
COUNT: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here is that your loop has no end condition: your loop is not related to the cursor you opened, so it will loop forever, no matter the number of rows from the cursor.

If you need to loop over the results of a select query, this is a simple way:

```
create or replace procedure testLoop is
begin
    for rec in ( 
                select level as val 
                from dual 
                connect by level <= 5 
               )
    loop
        dbms_output.put_line(rec.val);
    end loop;
end;
```

The call:

```
SQL> exec testLoop;
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: I need to execute a query represented by a string. If I try 'for rec in (query_string) ' I get an error (LOOP symbol found rather than &-+)